# How do you compute the Fourier Transform of this Unit-Impulse Function?

Tags: fourier-analysis, signal-processing

I have been given this problem from a textbook (not homework, trying to study for an exam.  The goal is to find the Fourier transform of this function.

$\sum_{k=0}^\infty a^k*\delta(t-kT), |a|<1$

Can anyone give me a hint or point me in the right direction of how to compute the Fourier Transform?  Thanks!

Comment: Find the Fourier transform of each summand.  Then you end up with a geometric series.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The FT of each individual impulse is

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dt \, \delta(t-k T) \, e^{i \omega t} = e^{i k \omega T}$$

so that the FT of the sum is a geometric series:

$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \left ( a \, e^{i \omega T}\right )^k = \frac{1}{1-a \, e^{i \omega T}}$$

Comment: Thank you so much! However, isn't the first integral equal to $e^{-ikwT}$?

Comment: @aikitect: No.  Note that $$\int dt \, \delta(t-a) f(t) = f(a)$$